# Working of SQL Server Replace Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, replace

Can anyone explain why the [`Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) function does not replace all the occurrences of `string_pattern` with `string_replacement` ?

```
select REPLACE(' A A A A ',' A ',' B ')
```

**Output:**   `B A B A`

**Expected Output:**  `B B B B`

```
select REPLACE('.A.A.A.A.','.A.','.B.')
```

**Output:**   `.B.A.B.A.`

**Expected output:**  `.B.B.B.B.`

In the above query why only the alternate values are replaced?

I know the above problem can be fixed by adding **one more replace** like.

```
select replace(REPLACE('.A.A.A.A.A.A.A.A.A.','.A.','.B.'),'.A.','.B.')
```

But why single `Replace` **does not replace** all the occurrence of `string_pattern` with `string_replacement`

Can anyone explain whats going on?

Comment: I can only guess but perhaps after the first replace of ` A ` it doesn't go back and re-evaluate the whole string. In which case the search starts from the next `A` rather than the space before that first A.

Comment: If the separators are consistent why not replace without matching on the trailing space eg `select REPLACE(' A A A A ',' A',' B')`

Comment: @ChrisMoutray that is just an example. what about this one `select REPLACE('.A.A.A.A.','.A.','.B.')`. I want to know how it works

Comment: I think my first comment pretty much explains it. The 2nd space isn't considered because its included in the 1st match.

Comment: So for you 2nd example again you don't include the trailing separator ie `REPLACE('.A.A.A.A.','.A','.B')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first space (or period) after the first `A` counts as part of the first match. Example:

```
.A.A.A.A.
111 222
```

The `1`s are the first match, and the `2`s are the second match. After finishing with the first replace, the function is looking at the second `A` and doesn't back up. `A.A` isn't a match, so it moves forward and looks at `.A.`.

Put differently, you are trying to match overlapping strings. It's like trying to replace `bob` with `job` in the following:

```
bobob
```

You're expecting to see `jojob`, but that's not how it works. After the first replace, you have `jobob`, but the replace function has already moved on to the second `o`. It doesn't see any more `bob`s, so it stops.

Answer (score 0):

to get the desire output you should Replace 'A' with 'B', without including space

Like

```
SELECT REPLACE(' A A A A ', 'A', 'B')
```

and

```
SELECT REPLACE('.A.A.A.A.', 'A', 'B')
```